# flexpaper implementation acting odd on XP

Tags: javascript, flexpaper

I have a site that I've implemented flexpaper on and it's working beautifully, or so i thought. I had a user email me yesterday because she was trying to view a document and couldn't because it was so small.

Turns out when flexpaper loaded the document in, it set the zoom to -3%, I don;t know if she realized it and was just complaining about the fact that it loaded that way, or genuinely thought it was broken. Changing the zoom is easy enough, but rather annoying to have to do it every time you load a document.

I don't know if it had the same behavior in IE, but she had this problem in firefox. On both my machine, co-workers machines, and her co-workers machines, it works fine, but we are all running vista and 7. Once we loaded up an XP machine, the zoom problem showed itself.

I know there's a zoom function in the API so I can hard set the zoom, but I'm interested to know if anyone else has come across this and if anyone knows what the cause is. I would like to fix it if it's something that can be fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never figured out why it did this, but changing the zoom settings, setting fitwidthonload to false and scale to 1 made it work just fine.